# Why is the action of lowering operator on the ground state of a harmonic oscillator to give a 0 wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, vacuum, ground-state

In quantum mechanics of the harmonic oscillator, when we use the operator method to find out the solutions, we find that the action of $\hat{a}$ is to lower the energy of a state by $\hbar\omega$ and the action of $\hat{a}^\dagger$ is to raise the energy by $\hbar\omega$. And so we claim that the action of the lowering operator on the ground state $\phi_0$ would be
$\hat{a}\phi_0=0$ and we use this to calculate the ground-state wave function and so on. But I have neither found not been able to construct a good enough argument as to why $\hat{a}\phi_0=0$. Why not something other than 0? or maybe some other wave function entirely?

It would be very nice if you could provide arguments in terms of wave functions and not the vectors as the Dirac notation confuses me as I am taking a quantum mechanics course for the first time and we have not covered that yet.

Comment: If your understand that $\phi(x)=\langle x|\phi\rangle$, I believe that your can easily understand this point: $a|\phi\rangle=0\rightarrow \langle x|a|\phi\rangle\rightarrow a\phi=0$.

Comment: How did you get $a|\phi\rangle=0$?

Comment: Is the question here why there isn't an infinite descending chain of energy states rather than stopping at some value?

Comment: Yes. I am actually confused as to why does the lowering operator anihillate the ground state entirely and not give any other wave function. Although, i do understand that the energy can't be less than 0 as the expectation value of hamilltonian is strictly positive.

Comment: The point is that $[H,a]=-\omega a$. Which means if $\psi$ is the ground state, with energy $E_0$, it has to be killed by $a$, for otherwise $a\psi$ would have energy $E_0-\omega$ contradicting the assumption that $\psi$ was the ground state. This is most likely explained by whatever source you are following.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on J. Murray's answer (which basically is the answer), we can start from the so-called number operator and have $\hat{N} = a^{\dagger}a$. As it was explained Murray's answer, its spectrum is non-negative, because
$$ \langle \psi | \hat{N} | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | a^{\dagger}a | \psi\rangle = || a|\psi\rangle ||^2 \geq 0$$
so every eigenvector $|n\rangle$ must have non-negative eigenvalue $n$ (currently no assumption on $n$. Can be fractional, can be integer, who knows?)

Now an important point is 
that $[\hat{N},a]=-a$, which means that if $|n\rangle$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $n$, then, applying this commutator we get 
$$ \hat{N} a |n\rangle = a(\hat{N}-1)|n\rangle = (n-1)a|n\rangle$$
so $a|n\rangle$ is also an eigenvector of $\hat{N}$ with an eigenvalue $n-1$! This means that if we start with some arbitrary eigenvector, we can create a series of eigenvectors with decreasing eigenvalues, just by repeatedly applying $a$, hurray! The only problem is that we know that this series cannot go on endlessly. It **must** stop otherwise we will get to negative eigenvalues territory, which cannot be true. So the **only** way for this series of lowering eigenvalues to stop is if it exactly hits zero. Then we don't have a state any more, and acting with $a$ on the zero vector just remains zero. So the eigenvalues $n$ have to be the non-negative integers. The state with the lowest possible eigenvalue has to be $a|0\rangle = 0$.

Edit: I just now noticed your last paragraph where you asked for the answer to be in terms of wave-functions. So you can start with
$$ \int\! dx \psi^*(x) \hat{N} \psi(x) = \int\! dx |a\psi(x)|^2 \geq 0$$ ensuring that the eigenvalues of $\hat{N}$ are nonnegative, and then have $$ \hat{N} a \psi_n(x) = a(\hat{N}-1)\psi_n(x) = (n-1)a\psi_n(x)$$ telling us that $a\psi_n(x)$ is a wavefunction which is an eigenfunction of $\hat{N}$ with eigenvalue $n-1$. Other than that all progresses as before

Comment: I would be very glad if you could answer these two questions-
$\\$(1) How do infer from $\langle\hat{N}\rangle\geq0$ that $\hat{N}$ has non-negative eigenvalues?
$\\$(2) How did you arrive at the conclusion that states of nth energy level $(\phi_n)$ have eigenvalues of $\hat{N}$ as n? As far as I know, it comes from the structure of the Hamiltonian and knowing that $E_n=(n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega$ but this result comes from taking $\hat{a}\phi_0=0$ and then using the equal spacing to derive this result.

Comment: (1) since $\langle \psi| \hat{N}|\psi\rangle \geq 0$ for *any* state, it should be true also for an eigenstate $|n\rangle$ for which $\langle \psi| \hat{N}|\psi\rangle=n$. So any eigenstate must satisfy this.
(2) I didn't talk about the energy, as this is a property of the operator $\hat{N} = a^{'dagger}a$ as can be inferred no matter how we reach it. In the context of the Harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian, indeed we have $H = \hbar\omega (\hat{N}+1/2)$ so up to a constant $H$ and $N$ are the same, so we can apply what we know of $\hat{N}$ to the energy eigenvalues

Comment: note that we know that $H=\hbar\omega(\hat{N}+1/2)$ by construction and independently of the spectrum of $\hat{N}$ and its eigenvectors.

Comment: But how do you know the action of $\hat{N}$ on the energy eigenfunctions $\phi_n$ is to factor out a n?

Comment: I know that $\hat{N}$ **has** eigenfunctions (because it is a Hermitian operator), and therefore **has** some eigenvalues which I denote by $n$ (not restricting it to any specific value). Then, from the arguments in my answer, I discover that these $n$ must be the non-negative integers $0,1,2,\ldots$. Then, using the identity $H=\hbar\omega(\hat{N}+1/2)$ I conclude that the same eigenfunctions of $\hat{N}$, must be also eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian, with energies $E_n = \hbar\omega(n+1/2)$.

Comment: Oh shoot. I completely missed that. I now understand your answer. It's pretty ingenious. But, a last short doubt. I know that the eigenfunctions of $\hat{N}$ are eigenfunctions of $\hat{H}$ but how do I know that these are all the eigenfunctions of $\hat{H}$ and there are no more. And again, thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: The operators $H$ and $\hat{N}$ are basically the same operators. Every eigenfunction of one of them is an eigenfunction of the other. You can question how do we know that we got all eigenfunctions of $\hat{N}$, and you're right - they might be more. However this mean that $N$ is degenerate, as all these functions must terminate with the eigenvalue $n=0$ upon enough applications of $a$, and we know that in 1d there is no degeneracy of bound-state solutions. So we found all eigenfunctions.

Answer (score 11):

The eigenstates of the operator $N = a^\dagger a$ can be labeled by their eigenvalues, i.e. $N \phi_n = n \phi_n$, where $n$ is an integer.  Note that
$$n = \langle \phi_n,N\phi_n\rangle = \underbrace{\langle\phi_n,a^\dagger a \phi_n\rangle = \langle a \phi_n,a\phi_n\rangle}_{a \text{ and } a^\dagger\text{ are mutually adjoint}} = \Vert a \phi_n\Vert^2 \geq 0 $$

In particular, we have that
$$ 0 = \Vert a\phi_0 \Vert^2$$
Since the only element of a Hilbert space with zero norm is the zero vector itself, we have that
$$a \phi_0 = 0$$

Comment: How do you go about saying that $0=||a\phi_0||^2$ and not something else?

Comment: @Tachyon209 Just let $n=0$ in that first expression I wrote.

Comment: Sorry to ask if this is trivial, but how do you write n as expectation of N for $\phi_n$ ?

Comment: @Tachyon209 If you understand that $N\phi_n = n \phi_n$, then $\langle \phi_n, N\phi_n\rangle = \langle \phi_n, n \phi_n\rangle = n \langle \phi_n,\phi_n\rangle = n$.

Comment: But you are taking another assumption that n is an integer. How do you ensure there are no states woth negative n?

Comment: Or not doing all of this, I meant to ask in this question whether there is any argument by which you can say that setting $a\phi=0$ makes sense?

Comment: @Tachyon209 I'm not making that assumption, I assumed you were already aware that the eigenvalues of $N$ are integers because you didn't ask about it.  As for how I know that there are no negative $n$, please take another look at the line where I demonstrate fairly clearly that $n \geq 0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105658/discussion-between-tachyon209-and-j-murray).

Comment: This derivation is circular. OP is completely justified by being confused by it.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform In what sense is it circular?  It starts from the premise that the eigenvalues of $N$ are integers and demonstrates that $a\phi_0$ has zero norm.  I assumed that was a reasonable starting point based on the context of the question - if not, then the answer is incomplete, but I'm not sure how it is circular.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by direct substitution in the position or momentum basis. Here it is for $x$:

\begin{align}
\hat a|0\rangle
&= \left[i\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\left(\hat x - \frac i {m\omega}\hat p \right) \right] \left[\left(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right)
e^{-mwx^2/2\hbar} \right]\\
&\propto \left[x+\frac {\hbar}{m\omega}\frac d{dx} \right]e^{-mwx^2/2\hbar}\\
&\propto xe^{-mwx^2/2\hbar}+\frac {\hbar}{m\omega}(-m\omega x/\hbar )e^{-mwx^2/2\hbar} \\
&= 0 \, .
\end{align}

Comment: Actually, we derive the ground state wave function by assuming that $\hat{a}\phi=0$. So, this is kind of a circular argument. I mean to ask why did we take the particular assumption that $\hat{a}\phi=0$?

Comment: That is one way to get the ground state wavefunction, but there are others. One way is just to write down all the energy eigenstates and find the one with the lowest energy.

Comment: @d_b OP asked why you can assume $\hat{a} \phi=0$, from which you can derive the wave function of above of the ground state. You can brute force solve the Schroedinger equation, but it is not what the OP asked.