# Is the average position for the ground state of a 1D simple harmonic oscillator zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, ground-state

My textbook claims the average position of the $n$-th state of 1D simple harmonic oscillator (SHO) is zero, which means

$$
\def\bra #1{\langle #1 |}
\def\ket #1{| #1 \rangle}
\def\braket #1{\langle #1 \rangle}
\def\l {\left}
\def\r {\right}
\braket{n | X | n} = 0
$$

where

$$\begin{align*}
X &= \sqrt\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega} \l(a + a^\dagger \r) \\
a &\equiv{\sqrt {m\omega  \over 2\hbar }}\left({X}+{i \over m\omega }{P}\right)\\
{a}^{\dagger } &\equiv {\sqrt {m\omega  \over 2\hbar }}\left({X}-{i \over m\omega }{P}\right)
\end{align*}$$

$a$ and $a^\dagger$ are ladder operators.

I tried to derive the statement by applying the ladder operators on the (eigen)states. When $n \ge 1$, it's 0. However, it's not true for $n = 0$. I got

$$\braket{0 | X | 0} = \sqrt\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}$$

This is weird. The wave function of the ground state of a 1D SHO is an even function in the position, so the average position should be zero.

Is the average position for the ground state of a 1D SHO zero? If it's not zero what does the result mean?

**Note:** I removed most of the equations I posted originally because the equations make others feel this question is a "check-my-work" question. If you hit the same problem as me, check the removed equations in the edit histories for more details.

Comment: Hint: $\langle 0|a|0\rangle \neq \langle 0|0\rangle$ and likewise for $a^\dagger$. And further, even *if* this would hold, then you're missing a factor of $2$, no?

Comment: $x$ is odd, ground state is even, so you must get 0.

Comment: Maybe the Dirac notation confuses you. Write it in mathematical notation as $\langle \phi_0 | (a+a^\dagger) \phi_0 \rangle=\langle \phi_0 | a \phi_0 \rangle +\langle \phi_0 | a^\dagger \phi_0 \rangle =\langle \phi_0 |a \phi_0 \rangle + \langle a \phi_0 | \phi_0 \rangle$. As $a \phi_0 =0$, both terms vanish.

Comment: I answered a question some time ago about [how to use ladder operators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82691/25301), it may be of use to you.

Comment: Also, it might be useful for an answer to indicate how you were able to obtain zero for $n\neq0$, as that might indicate where your understanding is flawed.

Comment: If $\langle 0\vert a^\dagger \vert 0\rangle=0$, then $\langle 0\vert a^\dagger \vert 0\rangle^\dagger= \langle 0\vert a\vert 0\rangle^*=0^*=0$.

Comment: Graphing the [probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#/media/File:Aufenthaltswahrscheinlichkeit_harmonischer_Oszillator.png) (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator)) for the position of the oscillating particle makes it *visually* clear that the average position is zero in every energy eigenstate, without doing any ladder-operator algebra or evaluating any integrals.

Comment: $a|0\rangle$ is not $|0\rangle$ but the vector $0$, which is a different vector with a similar notation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141754/discussion-on-question-by-ivanagyro-is-the-average-position-for-the-ground-state).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ladder operators raise and lower the states:
\begin{align}
  a\vert n\rangle &=\sqrt{n}\vert n-1\rangle \\
  a^\dagger\vert n\rangle &=\sqrt{n+1}\vert n+1\rangle
\end{align}
If you close the above two off with $\langle n\vert$, you end up with
\begin{align}
  \langle n\vert a\vert n\rangle &=\sqrt{n}\,\langle n\vert n-1\rangle \\
  \langle n\vert a^\dagger\vert n\rangle &=\sqrt{n+1}\,\langle n\vert n+1\rangle
\end{align}
Which, due to the orthogonality of the states of the QHO, are all zero, regardless of the state $n$.

In particular for the ground state,

- $a\vert0\rangle\equiv0$ by definition (cannot lower the lowest state); see also [this PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536825/25301)
- $\langle0\vert1\rangle=0$ by orthogonality

Hence, your two terms are not 1 as you suggested but 0:
\begin{align}
\langle 0\vert x\vert0\rangle &\sim \langle 0\vert (a+a^\dagger)0\rangle \\
 &= \langle0\vert a\vert0\rangle+\langle0\vert a^\dagger\vert0\rangle \\
 &= 0 + \langle0\vert1\rangle \\
 &= 0 + 0 \equiv 0
\end{align}

Comment: Just to emphasise the key feature that's missing in the OP calculations: the ground state, $|0\rangle$ (i.e. $|n\rangle$ for $n=0$), and the zero vector, $0$, are different things. The notation can be confusing at the start, but it becomes clear very soon what advantages in convenience and conciseness it offers.