# Finding the Expectation Value of Position for Generic $|n\rangle$ State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, notation

For a homework problem I had to write the position and impulse operators in terms of the creation and annihilation operators. The result is as follows:

$$\hat{x} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega }} (a + a^\dagger) \\
\hat{p} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar w \omega}{2}} i (a^\dagger - a).$$

From here I am to find the expectation values of $\langle x \rangle, \langle x^2 \rangle, \langle p \rangle \; \text{and} \; \langle p^2 \rangle$, using a wave function defined in the following way:

$$\psi_n (x) = \langle x | n \rangle.$$

This is what I tried to solve the problem, but I don't think my solution makes much physical sense:

\begin{align}
\langle x \rangle &= \int^\infty_{-\infty} \langle \psi_n | \hat{x} | \psi_n \rangle \text{d}x \\&= \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \langle n | x \rangle (\langle x | a^\dagger n \rangle + \langle x | a n \rangle) \text{d}x \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}} \biggl( \sqrt{n+1} \langle n| \int^\infty_{-\infty} |x \rangle \langle x| \; \text{d}x \; |n+1 \rangle \; + \sqrt{n} \langle n | \int^\infty_{-\infty} |x \rangle \langle x | \; \text{d}x \; |n-1 \rangle \biggr) \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}} (\sqrt{n+1} \langle n | n+1 \rangle + \sqrt{n} \langle n | n-1 \rangle) = 0
\end{align}

I'm still very unsure when it comes to Dirac notation, and I've more or less hit a brick wall. What did I do wrong and how is this problem to be solved?

Comment: Why doesn't $\langle x\rangle=0$ make physical sense?

Comment: Essentially a dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743237/25301

Comment: well I assume the particle has to be located somewhere in space, thus I would expected it to have a real valued positive non zero expectation value for its location. but maybe I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: @YasenY. That the expectation value is zero just means, roughly speaking, that you expect the particle to be found at $x=0$...nothing particularly strange here.

Comment: A lot of great answers here, I'm just going to add a suggestion that can help you convince yourself that things are working out as they should. Consider a shifted wavefunction $\bar{\psi}_n(x) = \psi_n (x-x_0)$. What is the expectation value of the position operator for this new state? Does it correspond to what you would expect?

Answer (score 0):

$\langle x\rangle=0$ holds for multiple reasons.

Physically, the probability density $\vert\psi_n(x)\vert^2$ is symmetric about $x=0$ so you have equal probability of finding the particles in the $x<0$ and in the $x>0$ region: the average is thus $0$.

In addition to your (correct) calculation, the function $\vert\psi_n(x)\vert^2 x$ is an odd function of $x$ so (being slightly careless with the math), it makes perfect sense for
$$
\int_{-a}^a dx \vert \psi_n(x)\vert^2 x =0 
$$
based on parity.  It's then just a matter of taking $a\to\infty$;  again some math about taking the limits for improper integrals go under the rug but the argument is sufficiently intuitive to be believable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the action of the operators $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ is defined on the state |n>. When you compute the expectation value $<\hat{x}>$ this must be computed on the state |n>, not on $\psi_n (x)$, which is a functional and not a state.
In the dirac notation a functional is a bra-ket. So if you write $|\psi_n>$, this is wrong if you have just specificate $\psi_n$ as a functional.
So you have $$<n|\hat{x}|n>$$ From this you can compute the expectation value using the annihilation and creation operators.

Note that $$<n|\hat{x}|n> = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dx dx' <n|x><x|\hat{x}|x'><x'|n>} = (*) $$
Here i have just insert two times the identity $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dx |x><x|} = \mathbf{1}$. So i have projected the abstract hilbert state |n> on the position space, gaining the functional $\psi_n(x) = <x|n>$. (You can do the same thing in the momentum space, with $\hat{p}$, using $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dp|p><p|}$).
$$ (*) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dxdx' \psi_n^*(x)\cdot x' \delta(x-x') \cdot \psi(x') } = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dx \cdot \psi_n^*(x)\cdot x \cdot \psi_n(x)} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{|\psi_n(x)|^2 x dx} $$
This give us the physical interpretation of the matrix element (*), it is the main value of the position of a particle in a region $(-\infty,\infty
)$.

Anyway your result is correct, is incorrect only the notation that you have used to solve the problem.

Comment: `\langle` and `\rangle` in MathJax blocks will yield the correct symbols, rather than using less-than and greater-than symbols.

Comment: thank you i usually use \ket  and \bra on latex but there doesnt' work

Comment: Probably because (a) \ket and \bra are part of the LaTeX physics package (which I believe is strongly recommended against using due to a plethora of issues) and (b) we have [MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/tex.html), not LaTeX here.